# Is it possible to write a driver for NCR Caash Dispenser using its protocol

Tags: c#, devise, driver, protocols

I am trying to implement an NCR dispenser driver using its protocol. Is it possible to do this? Or there is a ready-made open source driver.
A year ago I needed a driver (library for control) for Puloon LCDM 2000 (dispenser). I found the sources for Puloon LCDM 4000 from github and modified it for Puloon LCDM 2000, now it works very well. Now I need the same driver for the NCR dispenser. I searched the internet for the NCR dispenser protocol but couldn't find it. Where can I find the protocol?

Comment: I believe applications should be written using the 7 Network Layers.  In this case the low level hardware interface is serial like Ethernet, RS-232, or USB which is a driver in windows.  Do you want to build into the driver the LCDM conversion or do you want to put into application layer?  In windows you can have a two layer driver.  One layer is the hardware layer and the other a protocol layer.  See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23

Comment: I need to write a command to control an NCR dispenser. For example, I need to write a command to withdraw $100 from a cassette tape.

Comment: Copied wrong link.  This specification is for NCR CDM (not LCDM).  May be similar : https://www.cencenelec.eu/media/CEN-CENELEC/AreasOfWork/CEN%20sectors/Digital%20Society/CWA%20Download%20Area/XFS/CWA16926_Release3.40/TrackChanges/cwa-16926-64.pdf?force_isolation=true